# Detecting if a window is open

Tags: applescript

How do I detect if my dialog window has closed?

- I open a dialog window
- Then I want to read the window header value and display the results
- Then I close the window
- Then I want to detect if the window dialog closed

  on DatabaseRefresher()
  menu_click({"OsiriX", "Plugins", "Database", "SetRemoteDatabaseRefresh"})
  delay 1
  set Test1 to 0
  set Test1 to value of static text "RemoteDatabasePrefs" of window "RemoteDatabasePrefs" of application process "OsiriX" of application "System Events"
  log Test1
  PressButton("Cancel", "OsiriX", "RemoteDatabasePrefs") --(TheButtonToPress, TheProgramName, TheWindow)
  Add test here to detect if window closed)
  end DatabaseRefresher

Here are my window elements:

```
button "OK" of window "RemoteDatabasePrefs" of application process "OsiriX" of application "System Events", 
button "Cancel" of window "RemoteDatabasePrefs" of application process "OsiriX" of application "System Events", 
text field 1 of window "RemoteDatabasePrefs" of application process "OsiriX" of application "System Events", 
static text "RemoteDatabasePrefs" of window "RemoteDatabasePrefs" of application process "OsiriX" of application "System Events"
static text "Enter Remote Database Refresh Interval in minutes:" of window "RemoteDatabasePrefs" of application process "OsiriX" of application "System Events", 
button 3 of window "RemoteDatabasePrefs" of application process "OsiriX" of application "System Events", 
button 4 of window "RemoteDatabasePrefs" of application process "OsiriX" of application "System Events", 
button 5 of window "RemoteDatabasePrefs" of application process "OsiriX" of application "System Events",
```

As a noob, my apologies if I am asking very basic questions.  I do have some existing scripts to work with and I seem to know how they work, but when I try to refactor them I seem to spend too much time find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is a bit odd:

```
set Test1 to value of static text "RemoteDatabasePrefs" of window "RemoteDatabasePrefs" of ...
```

`static text` objects are typically named after the value of the text they contain.  Therefore, I would *expect* the `value` of that `static text` to be `"RemoteDatabasePrefs"`.

But, if this is being done in order to get the header text of a window, you don't need to read the value of some `static text` object; you can access the `name` property or the `title` property for the `window` object instead:

```
set Test1 to the title of window "RemoteDatabasePrefs" of ...
```

The `name` property is clearly set to `"RemoteDatabasePrefs"`; `title` properties are often identical to the `name`, and both usually match the text in the header bar of the window.  However, you may have come across an exception, where the `name` and `title` properties are different in value; in which case, you'll want the value of the `title` property, which should match the header text.

---

To test that the window has been closed, you use the `exists` command to test whether or not the `window` object still exists.  When a window is closed, it ceases to exist from that point onwards.

```
tell application "System Events to tell process "OsiriX"
    set isOpen to (exists window "RemoteDatabasePrefs")
end tell
```

The variable `isOpen` will then contain a boolean value `true` or `false` telling you whether the window is open (`true`) or has been closed (`false`).